# Drawing circles around cells after watershed segmentation - openCV/Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation, watershed

I followed a tutorial on watershed segmentation and used it to segment each red blood cell in an image. I'm new to openCV and I would like to know if it is possible to draw circles around the cells by using watershed segmentation? If so, could you please show how it is done.

Original image

[image: original image]

Output of Watershed segmentation

[image: Watershed output]

Code is given below

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def fillHoles(otsuImg):
    # find contours
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(otsuImg, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    # filter out contours by size
    small_cntrs = []
    for con in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(con)
        # print(area)
        if area < 1000: # size threshold
            small_cntrs.append(con)
    cv2.drawContours(otsuImg, small_cntrs, -1, 0, -1)

# load the image
img = cv2.imread('resources/rbc2.png')
img_pyr = cv2.pyrMeanShiftFiltering(img, 21, 51)
img_median = cv2.medianBlur(img_pyr, 9)
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_median, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, img_thresh = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# fill holes of RBC
fillHoles(img_thresh)

# invert the image
img_thresh = cv2.bitwise_not(img_thresh)

# noise removal
kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(img_thresh,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernel, iterations=2)

# sure background area
sure_bg = cv2.dilate(opening,kernel,iterations=3)

# Finding sure foreground area
dist_transform = cv2.distanceTransform(opening,cv2.DIST_L2, 5)
ret, sure_fg = cv2.threshold(dist_transform,0.1*dist_transform.max(),255,0)
# _, sure_fg = cv2.threshold(np.uint8(dist_transform), 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# Finding unknown region
sure_fg = np.uint8(sure_fg)
unknown = cv2.subtract(sure_bg, sure_fg)

# Marker labelling
ret, markers = cv2.connectedComponents(sure_fg)

# Add one to all labels so that sure background is not 0, but 1
markers = markers+1

# Now, mark the region of unknown with zero
markers[unknown==255] = 0

markers = cv2.watershed(img,markers)
img[markers == -1] = [255,0,0]


cv2.imshow('markers2', np.uint8(markers))
cv2.imshow('Final output', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: I'm not certain I know exactly what you want to do here. You could use minEnclosingCircle to draw a circle around each of the blobs, but I get the feeling that isn't really what you're looking for. Do you want to be able to separate overlapping cells and approximate a circle to each of them?

Comment: plz use paint function to draw out a sample of what you want. medical imaging has many objectives some aim to find high gradient/ intensity area. some aim to look at geometry shape. different objective/task will determine which algorithm to use. As far as i know, watershed is one of the most fundamental method in opencv. since your cell has prior shape, a variational based shape prior may help in segment what you want

Comment: @IanChu Yes, I want to separate the overlapping cells and draw a circle around them. Though my implementation of the Watershed algorithm was not able to properly isolate all of the overlapping cells. Do you have a workaround for this? Also, can you show me how I can implement the minEnclosingCircle in my code above? I've only started learning OpenCV days ago and I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and ended up using `skimage.segmentation.watershed` for the last step, to get the labels I could use to calculate the contours of the watershed cells. Once you have the contours, you can calculate and plot the enclosing circle as usual:

```py
    # your code above
    ret, markers = cv2.connectedComponents(sure_fg)
    from skimage.segmentation import watershed
    labels = watershed(-dist_transform,
                              markers,
                              mask=img_thresh,
                              watershed_line=False)
    watershed_contours = list(map(lambda l: cv2.findContours((labels == l).astype(np.uint8),
                                cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[0][0],
                                np.unique(labels)[1:]))
    output = img.copy()
    for contour in watershed_contours:
        (x,y),radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(contour)
        center = (int(x),int(y))
        radius = int(radius)
        cv2.circle(output,center,radius,(0,255,0),2)
```

Comment: >cv_labels == l   there is no variable cv_labels in your provided code

Comment: You are right. It referred to the labels calculated by the watershed function from skimage. I have edited the response to reflect this. Thanks a lot for catching that!